# How can I get list of all participants of meeting created by using MS Graph APIs ,

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created meeting link using MS Graph API of create meeting, My this API returns VideoConferencingID as null and audioConferencingID as null. SO I tried to call API to get participants with below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants
but no success. I also used CallRecord API. But didn't work. Can anyone help me to get all participants with API?

Comment: You need to create the online meeting using create [online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) . In the response you will receive the meeting id , by using that meeting id you can get the meeting details by using GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/id .

Comment: Hi @varaprasad-msft, I have tried above API too, I have one query that where is thst meeting ID in response as there are msny ID return like Id, tandnt Id etc, srcond thind I tried Id , tanent Id and there is Id under user that is my id all return error, there is Id parameter at second line from top that is very long but it returns same information that i got from onlinemeeting api without id.

Comment: Please check the is id above the joinwebURL in the response. Here is the [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef5NF.png) for the same

Comment: Hi  @Nikitha-MSFT, I am using id that you mentioned in screenshot that I got after execute https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings API. Then I got id: "7aa51015-6983-8b4b-88b703e92807_19:meeting_ODk2NmEyMWMtNzBmOS00ZjU2LTlmYTEtNjQ2MTNlOWIxMjAw@thread.v2", then I copy this ID as it is and I use it as below:

Comment: I am using similar id that I got after execute https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings API. I copies ID as it is and I use it as below:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/7aa51015-6983-8b4b-88b703e92807_19:meeting_1ZGMwZDYwODk2@thread.v2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/7aa51015-6983-8b4b-88b703e92807_19:meeting_1ZGMwZDYwODk2@thread.v2/participants . 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/7aa51015-6983-8b4b-88b703e92807_19:meeting_MwZDYwODk2@thread.v2
but above APIs doesn't return attendees/participants

Comment: By using that meeting id which you received in the response you can get the meeting details by using GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/id

Comment: I tried but it returns same result without participants detail. I think microsoft doesn't provide any API to get participants.

Comment: Could you please share the request URL and response of what you are seeing?